# Please convey as early as possible

Tags: mobile, titanium

I have created an app for android phones in titanium studio.Please suggest me how to make it flexible for tablet.
one of my friend suggested to do through adjusting width in %

Comment: Questions should be clear and specific. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your TiApp.xml

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

That will make the app default to the same style that the older versions of titanium used, where it basically scales them according to the device in use. If you use any images in your application, try to use high resolution images